# Xubuntu - command/shortcut to hide all notifications

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, notification

Is there a command/shortcut avaiable to hide all popped-up notifications? Some of my scripts produce notifications which dont auto-hide, you have to click them.

I'd like to have a keyboard shortcut instead of having to click each and every one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such shortcut. Even then, the notification interface does not expose a DBus call to revoke all open notifications.

However, you can speedily dispose all by killing the notification process:

**Quick and dirty:**

Assign the shortcut of your liking to:

```
pkill xfce4-notifyd
```

**Sophisticated and nerdy:**

Ask it to terminate gracefully:

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.Notifications \
                   /org/freedesktop/Notifications \
                   org.xfce.Notifyd.Quit
```

Or maybe put the above in your scripts.

**Note:** Ending the `xfce4-notifyd` process is not an issue because the next invocation of a notification will start the process. It will even self-terminate when there is nothing to display for some time.

Comment: Still works like a charm more than seven years later. Thank you ;).